# Is there a way to use classes as type hints for python's built-in numeric types?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types, numbers, type-hinting

I want to create a class that can be used as a type hint for any of python's built-in numeric types, such as int, float, complex, or a class that inherits from number.Number

I want something like this:

```python
from fractions import Fraction


class AnyNumber(<whatever here>):
    ...


def foo(number: AnyNumber):
    ...


foo(1)  # Valid
foo(1.0)  # Valid
foo(1j)  # Valid
foo(Fraction())  # Also valid
```

How can I do it?

I have also tried using numbers.Number as a type hint, but my Pylance and mypy say something like 'int is not compatible with Number'.

Is there another way to do this without using `Union`?

Comment: Relevant issue: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3186 it seems you'd simply have to create your own `Protocol` to describe what you expect.

Comment: What features of a number do you want this class to have? i.e what are you going to do with the number?

Answer (score 0):

Since all possible numbers are complex numbers, you can use the protocol `typing.SupportsComplex` instead to type hint any number:

```
from typing import SupportsComplex
from fractions import Fraction

def foo(number: SupportsComplex):
    pass

foo(1)  # Valid
foo(1.0)  # Valid
foo(1j)  # Valid
foo(Fraction())  # Also valid
```

Demo:
https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=e327d5b393677e8b97b125d3184d74a6